# How to turn on Firefox dark theme without telling websites to turn dark?

Tags: firefox

I like Firefox's dark theme, but I don't like Firefox passing the theme info to many websites (e.g., Google, YouTube, etc.). How can I stop Firefox from doing this without changing the skin to the light theme?

Comment: It doesn't send any info to any website. It simply changes some style attributes in the HTML which the website sends to your browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this Reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/dgke1s/comment/hnpm5r3/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):

> Old thread but it turns out in google - the current way to do this is to set "layout.css.prefers-color-scheme.content-override" to 1 (0 - dark mode, 1 - light mode, 2 - system colors?, 3 - theme colors?)

Having faced the same problem with the newest Firefox version, I can confirm this works. Just set `layout.css.prefers-color-scheme.content-override` to `1` in `about:config` and web sites will appear in light mode.